# Android Google Maps, how to create navigation between 2 points

Tags: android, google-maps

I want to create a Map activity (FragmentActivity) that displays a Google Map and shows navigation between 2 points.

I have one made that shows one location but I've no idea on how to create navigation to another point, every link I saw gives their web api as the solution (https://maps.google.com/maps?saddr=X,Y&daddr=X,Y)

and I want to do exactly what it does just programmatically through the activity and not just link into their webpage

my code so far:

```
try{
    bndl = getIntent().getExtras();
    COORDS = new LatLng(bndl.getDouble("lat"), bndl.getDouble("long"));

if (map == null) {
    map = ((SupportMapFragment) getSupportFragmentManager().findFragmentById(R.id.map)).getMap();

    if (map != null) {
        map.setMapType(GoogleMap.MAP_TYPE_HYBRID);
        map.addMarker(new MarkerOptions().position(COORDS).title("Your parking spot!"));

        CameraPosition cameraPosition = new CameraPosition.Builder()
            .target(COORDS)     
            .zoom(20)                 
            .bearing(90)             
            .tilt(0)                  
            .build();                 
        map.animateCamera(CameraUpdateFactory.newCameraPosition(cameraPosition));


    }
}

}
catch (Exception e){
    Log.v("except", ""+e);
}
```

now this only shows the one location (as it should do) but how to create another marker or something to navitage to? Is there a way to do this or do I HAVE to use their web api?

Comment: Check out my library I made if you want to cheat and not learn how to do it yourself https://github.com/tyczj/MapNavigator

Comment: Well could you explain generally how you've done it so I can try for myself?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you could use this blog post guide I wrote on this topic:

[Google Maps API V2: Navigation using Polyline](http://blog-emildesign.rhcloud.com/?p=822)

There is a source project there with the implementation that you can use to achieve exactly what you want.

Comment: Can I use that API to calculate the time or distance? Also, can I use it with walking not just driving? I want to know before consuming my time learning it

Comment: How to show navigation route for bicycle on Google maps?